# Unable to retrieve the PostgreSQL database after attaching EBS volume to new EC2 Instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ebs

I have an EC2 instance with Root(`/dev/xvda`) and EBS(`/dev/xvdb`)volumes. Both are mounted.

I have installed PostgreSQL DB and inserted some data in it, then I have created a snapshot of EBS(`/dev/xvdb`)volume and then from this I have created a volume.

Now I have stopped my EC2 instance, and created a new EC2 instance with root volume and attached the old volume(`/dev/xvdb`) to this new instance.

Now, I have both root and EBS(`/dev/xvdf`). Both are mounted at `/` and `/data` directories.

I have installed PostgreSQL DB in my root volume, and now I can see the PostgreSQL data directory in new EC2 instance at `/data` directory, but when I enter into PostgreSQL shell and look for databases, I cannot see the database which was created in `/dev/xvdb` volume.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you double-check the psql data is captured in the snapshot?

Comment: Can you check which directory your cluster is using? I believe that as you installed Postgresql with and existent `/data` directory, the Postgres installation created and redirected your cluster to another directory.

Comment: I have 2 volumes in my old EC2 instance, and now I have created a new EC2 instance, removed root volume from new EC2 and attached both the volumes from old EC2 instance, and when I do SSH to new EC2, I can see postgresql is present and both the volumes are mounted to new EC2, when I get in to psql and list out the databases, I could not see the database name which I created in my first EC2 postgresql. All the postgresql config files are same in new EC2, but I could not figure it out how come the database is missing, even attaching the same volume. Any suggestions/help ???